# Internet Explorer security warning: want to view only the webpage content delivered securely?

Tags: security, browser, internet-explorer

Consider visiting a website using HTTPS. Internet Explorer (IE8 in this case) presents a warning:

[image]

> Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?

Clicking the More Info button leads to a bunch of other questions, but offers no indication on how to remove this prompt.

How do you adjust IE's settings to remove this security warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the IE Internet Options dialog
2. Select the 'Security' tab
3. Click the 'Custom Level' button
4. Find the 'Miscellaneous' section
5. Change 'Display mixed content' to 'Enable'

   [image]